# Does every java version come in both: 32 and 64 bit version?

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to install eclipse on my centOS 7, but I'm having big problems with my java. I have downloaded 64bit eclipse version. At first I had java 1.7 from oracle and I was getting some error saying 'JVM terminated. Exit code = 13'. So I upgraded to java 1.8 but I'm still getting the same error message. Now in both cases when I ran java -d64 I got a message that says that this java version doesn't support 64bit JVM. And hence my question. Does every java version come in both 32 and 64 bit flavors? If not then what is the first version that is 64bit. And even more important: where can I find this information on my own?

Comment: Note that recent versions of Eclipse require at least Java 8. The official Oracle [site](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) is fairly clear about which downloads are 32 bit (sometimes callled 'x86') and which 64 bit (x64)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see which versions of Java are available as 32 or 64 bit on the Oracle Download site

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

On here if a download contains 64 in its name it is 64 bit. If it says 586 or 32 then is is 32 bit.

Java 9 was the first version to be completely 64 bit.

Comment: So, to sum it up. There versions of Oracle jdk that don't have 32bit release, and 32 bit x86 is considered obsolete. There is open jdk and other providers out jkd /jvm which might provide 32 bit

Comment: I thought that 64 or 586 is the information about os architecture. So for example jdk-8u201-linux-x64.rpm can be installed only on 64bit os.

Comment: [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net) lists OpendJDK releases (HotSpot and OpenJ9) and has an [API to query and to download releases](https://api.adoptopenjdk.net/).